# Centered text but without hyphenation

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

For a heading I want to have a horizontally centered box with text. The text should not be hyphenated. If the text is not hyphenated the text should be still in the center of the page. Currently I have the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[unit=cm]{fgruler}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[tb]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{
        \parbox{.5\textwidth}{
            \raggedright
            \centering
            \hyphenpenalty=10000
            \exhyphenpenalty=10000
            \Huge\bfseries
            Mögliche einzelne Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten
        }
    }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which centers the box but not the text. Preferered solution would be to use "regular" LaTex-commands.

**UPDATE**:

- The `\fbox` was more for the purpose to highlight - or to spot - the problem more easily.
- The line break should be done more or less automatically - not introduced manually.
- The word `Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten` is just a random word which is quite long. This should just make clear that it should NOT be hyphenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the long word fits in the text block width, you can embed your text in `varwidth` and a standard `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \exhyphenpenalty=10000
    \Huge\bfseries
    Mögliche einzelne Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten
  \end{varwidth}%
}

\bigskip

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \begin{varwidth}{1.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \exhyphenpenalty=10000
    \Huge\bfseries
    Mögliche einzelne Constantinopolitanischerdudelsackspfeifenmachersgesellschafft
  \end{varwidth}%
}

\bigskip

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \begin{varwidth}{1.2\textwidth}
    \centering
%    \hyphenpenalty=10000
%    \exhyphenpenalty=10000
    \Huge\bfseries
    Mögliche einzelne Constantinopolitanischerdudelsackspfeifenmachersgesellschafft
  \end{varwidth}%
}

\end{document}
```

I added `showframe` only for the purpose of showing the margins.

[image]

The second and third examples show what happens when the long word exceeds the allotted space (complain with Mark Twain for the pseudo-German utterance).

Aside: the option `tb` to `minipage` isn't really meaningful. The optional argument should be a *single* character among `c`, `t` or `b`.

Comment: I like the word `Constantinopolitanischerdudelsackspfeifenmachersgesellschafft` ;-) and thx for pointing out about the parameter in the `minipage`. Just to sure: From your example I conclude that the `\makebox` replaces more or less the `minipage`

Answer (score 2):

You say the fbox was just to highlight the issue but adding the box makes it more complicated, if you just want a form of `center` that allows over-run on both sides just use left and right skip with enough shrink:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{center}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\leftskip=0pt plus\textwidth minus \textwidth
\rightskip=\leftskip
\Huge\bfseries

  Mögliche einzelne
  Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten

  Mögliche einzelne
  Constantinopolitanischerdudelsackspfeifenmachersgesellschafft
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This has a forces paragraph separation between the two examples, but uses automatic lienbreaking for each example.

Comment: I highly prefer your approach. One problem and one question: If I add `\usepackage{geometry}` (without any margins) the line break changes. Is there a way to keep it? And my additional question: For the calculation of `\leftskip` should I use `textwidth` or `linewidth`? (The q arises since its within a center enviornment and I'm not clear if there is difference between them)

Comment: @LeO theh shrink component doesn't matter much, anything large enough, you could use `\maxdimen`  as for the width of the block you could just set `\hsize=10cm`  inside the environment as well or whatever width you want and it will try to break to that, but allow overrun on both sides.

Comment: Ahhh- thx. And why does `geometry` interfere with the whole line break handling? Or better asked: How to keep the handling of line breaks for these paragraphs when using `geometry` as well?

Comment: I told it to linebreak to textwidth, if you change the textwidth then naturally the linebreaking will change. @LeO If you specify a specific text block with \hsize=... then  geometrry changing textwidth will just affect the margins not the linebreaking

Comment: Sorry, if I'm persistent. If I add `\usepackage{geometry}` to the given code I get NO linebreak between `einzelne Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten`. When I comment it I get a linebreak.

Comment: geometry will change the margins trey `\showthe\textwidth`  in each case

Answer (score 0):

Your word *Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten* is to long that can be fit in one line in text on page, consequently it spill out of your `\parbox`, `minipage` and text border too. It spill a bit out of right text border. Even worse is, when you try to insert in `\parbox{0.5\textwidth}`-

It is not clear, if you need `\fbox` or it serve only for emphasize your problem.

Possible remedy is not to use `\parbox` `and` \fbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[unit=cm]{fgruler}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering\Huge\bfseries
Mögliche einzelne
Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten
          \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or use smaller font size, for example `\huge`. In this case you will get:

[image]

**Addendum:**
Another way when smaller font size are used, is use of `savebox` for writing text and measured desired width}

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[unit=cm]{fgruler}
\newsavebox{\temp}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\fbox{\savebox{\temp}{\huge\bfseries Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\the\wd\temp}\centering\huge\bfseries
Mögliche einzelne \usebox{\temp}
          \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Where `Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten` in all above cases is the longest word in text or the longest text in one line of text.

Result is similar as before (difference is added frame around text}:

[image]

In the case that you like to have bigger font (`\Huge` for example) and that text/word which has not be hyphenated/split is wider than `\text width, then you may consider to employ` changepage` package and wrote your text (I suppose that it probably is some title) as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[unit=cm]{fgruler}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\newsavebox{\temp}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\marginparwidth}{-\marginparwidth}
\centering
\fbox{\savebox{\temp}{\Huge\bfseries Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\the\wd\temp}\centering\Huge\bfseries
Mögliche einzelne \usebox{\temp}
          \end{minipage}
    }
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the response which made clear that some points I didn't mentioned explicitly :-/ I've updated my question.

Comment: @LeO, but my answer do exactly what you listed in question. What is now the problem?

Comment: uhhh... seems I've missed to make my point clear .... the main problem is that the line break should NOT be manually done. Doing it manually isn't a big problem. I wouldn't raise a question because this I know how to do it ;-)

Comment: As you see now, it is not manually done (In first answer version I forgot to delete this par of code). I will provide some new version how to manage your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the superlong-but-not-to-be-hyphenated-under-any circumstance word in a `\makebox[0pt]{...}` wrapper.

[image]

Notes. (a) No need for `\hyphenpenalty=10000` and `\exhyphenpenalty=10000`. (b) With this approach, the superlong word could easily infringe into the margins.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[unit=cm]{fgruler}

\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{\widthof{\Huge\bfseries Mögliche einzelne}}{%
      \centering
      \Huge\bfseries
      Mögliche einzelne \par % or insert a blank line
      \makebox[0pt]{Zeilenumbruchsvielfaltmöglichkeiten}
    }
  }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```